# remove a field with a specific value from a document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have three documents in a collection with the following data

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc832db42756b4d38bba983"),
    "type" : "photo",    
    "severitylevel" : NumberLong(0),    
    "location" : {
        "loc" : {
            "lng" : 77.653322,
            "lat" : 13.06511
        }

}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc8338c42756b4d38bba9bb"),
    "type" : "text",    
    "severitylevel" : NumberLong(1),    
    "location" : {
        "loc" : {
            "lng" : 77.653322,
            "lat" : 13.06511
        }

}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc83d0c42756b8b3abba961"),
    "type" : "photo",    
    "severitylevel" : NumberLong(2),    
    "location" : {
        "loc" : {
            "lng" : 77.653322,
            "lat" : 13.06511
        }

}
```

Now I would like to remove the field severitylevel from the document only when the value is equal to 0 otherwise not by using a query.
Any suggestions on how this can be done

Comment: Not too daunting `db.collection.update({severitylevel: 0}, {$unset:{severitylevel:""}})` ?

Comment: let me try and see the output

Comment: yes it works ..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$unset` to remove the field from the document

```
db.collection.update({ severitylevel: 0 }, { $unset: { severitylevel: "" }})
```

Comment: Actually no one has marked it as duplicate. So I had to answer it.